# Get first legitimate email from row, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set where we have multiple email columns for a client, like,

- Primary Email
- Personal Email
- Work Email
- Contact email

The system I pull this information from doesn't collapse the email records down. Which means I might have the contact email filled in but not as the primary email. Is there a way using Pandas to eloquently collapse the data into the primary email column based on the first instance of a good email? I know I can somewhat brute force this by looping through the whole thing and doing a couple of if/else statements where I keep looking in each column until I get a proper result, but that doesn't feel very pythonic.

EX: Input

```
Email 1,    Email 2,   Email 3,    Email 4
                                   1@.com
            2@.com     4@.com
```

Turns into

```
Email 1,    Email 2,   Email 3,    Email 4
1@.com                             1@.com
2@.com      2@.com     4@.com
```

Comment: the missing emails are empty strings?

Comment: Not necessarily, I would only push the email string forward if it contains an "@"

Comment: so it could be NaN as well?

Comment: 99% of the time it is NaN. there are just a few fringe cases where people thought it was appropriate to enter something they shouldnt have.

Comment: i have over 40k records so there are still hundreds of exceptions. In other places where i process the emails I've found it easier to simply use the prescence of '@' as the matching condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try `bfill`, if there are not NaN , do `df=df.replace({'':np.nan})` before run below

```
df['Email 1']=df.bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
```

Comment: I need to work out the logic to only apply to the email columns but this should do it thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try (for both spaces and NaN):

```
s = df.stack()
df['Email 1'] = s.where(s.str.contains('@')).groupby(level=0).first()
```

---

```
print(df)

  Email 1 Email 2 Email 3 Email 4
0  1@.com     NaN          1@.com
1  2@.com  2@.com  4@.com     NaN
```

Comment: This also worked and i only half understand what is going on.

Comment: @Sam if YOBEN's answer work, that's the way to go, this answer specifically addresses invalid values where emails doesnot have `@` but other string values(`NaN` included). because this pulls first value with `@` per row

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using pandas `apply` function, you can try something like below,

```
df['Email 1'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.dropna()[0], axis=1)
```

Hope this helps.